# bootstrap - tab.js - сохраняет объект в элемент, зачем?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Кусок кода из bootstrap - tab.js:

```
var data  = $this.data('bs.tab')
if (!data) $this.data('bs.tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
```

Тут наверное даже вопрос не в "зачем", а в чем прелесть данного подхода?
Сохранять объект в Tab вкладку? Может кто объяснить, у кого есть опыт, почему такой подход? Если Tab-ов на странице много и в каждую вкладку Tab, по нажатию, сохраняется объект, разумно ли?

Comment: в дата хранится api, что позволяет управлять обьектом, без повторной инициализации, третья строка как раз использует это.

Comment: А может начать с сути и прочесть manual http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/